# Is this file compliant with the SMT2.0 standard?

Tags: z3, smt

[Click to see the file](http://seg.nju.edu.cn/BACH/Demo/water_1.smt2)

Is this file compliant with the SMT2.0 standard? At least, z3 can accpet it. By the way, what's the difference between 'declare-const' and 'declare-fun'? For example, in order to declare a Bool variable I can write `declare-const a Bool` or `declare-fun a() Bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to locate the file you mention in the post, but to answer your question about declare-const:

```
(declare-const a Bool)
```

means the same as

```
(declare-fun a () Bool)
```

declare-const is not part of standard SMT-LIB2. 
It is a command added to Z3 for the convenience of 
entering SMT-LIB2 benchmarks manually. You can
always use declare-fun instead to be compatible 
across solvers.

While Z3 can process SMT-LIB2 compliant files.
On the other hand, there are several other extensions in Z3's input format 
that are not part of SMT-LIB2 standard. 
To mention some:

- declare-datatypes. Declaration of algebraic datatypes is a Z3 specific extension.
- tactics and solvers. Creation, composition and application of tactics is specific to Z3.
- declare-rel, declare-var, rule, query. These commands are used by the fixedpoint solver for the convenience of entering benchmarks as Horn formulas.

Comment: The url of the file http://seg.nju.edu.cn/BACH/Demo/water_1.smt2. Thanks for your reply and I know the difference between 'declare-const' and 'declare-fun'.